# How to add custom host entries to kubernetes Pods?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

My application communicates to some services via hostnames.
When running my application as a docker container i used to add hostnames to the /etc/hosts of the hostmachine and run the container using `--net=host`.

Now I'm running my containers in kubernetes cluster. I would like to know how can i add the /etc/hosts entries to the pod via `yaml`.

I'm using kubernetes v1.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and also looks simpler:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
    name: {HOST_NAME} 
    spec:
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: {PORT}
          targetPort: {PORT}
      type: ExternalName
      externalName: {EXTERNAL_IP}
```

Now you can use the `HOST_NAME` from the pod directly to access the external machine.

Comment: Alas, this wouldn't let you to add a FQDN: `Invalid value: "example.com": a DNS-1035 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', start with an alphabetic character, and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or 'abc-123', regex used for validation is '[a-z]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')`

Comment: @beatcracker For this, you can use HostAliases to solve the problem. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/

Comment: @sunnykrgupta I'm using terraform and its k8s provider doesn't support `HostAliases` yet. I was hoping to achieve it via this hack, but alas...

Answer (score 12):

From k8s 1.7 you can add `hostAliases`. [Example from the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
```

Comment: Is this a new pod I have to add in current cluster ?

Comment: No, that's an example on how to add custom host entries

Answer (score 1):

Host files are going to give you problems, but if you really need to, you could use a configmap.

Add a configmap like so

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-app-hosts-file-configmap
data:
  hosts: |-
    192.168.0.1 gateway
    127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Then mount that inside your pod, like so:

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: my-app-hosts-file
      mountPath: /etc/
volumes:
  - name: my-app-hosts-file
    configMap:
    name: my-app-hosts-file-configmap
```

Comment: But this will override the default hosts file which contains the hostname of the pod.

Comment: Did you found any workaround to retain the hostname of the pod?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use **postStart** hook on the pod **lifecycle** as below:

> ```
> lifecycle:
>       postStart:
>         exec:
>          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo '192.168.1.10 weblogic-jms1.apizone.io' >> /etc/hosts; echo '192.168.1.20
> ```
>
> weblogic-jms2.apizone.io' >> /etc/hosts; echo '192.168.1.30
>   weblogic-jms3.apizone.io' >> /etc/hosts; echo '192.168.1.40
>   weblogic-jms4.apizone.io' >> /etc/hosts"]